# GNU Indent issue with GNU code style

Tags: c, indentation, gnu, osx-elcapitan, gnu-indent

I installed `indent` using `brew` thanks to the command `brew install gnu-indent` so now I have `gnu-indent-2.2.10` installed on my MacOS X so far, so good. My problem is when I want to indent a file using `GNU` code style.

I mean I would like to convert this:

```
while (foo) {
}
```

Into this:

```
while (foo) 
  {
  }
```

So following the documentation I launched `indent` with the parameter `-bl -bli2` in order to have the GNU code style with 2 spaces by which braces are indented but what I actually get is:

```
while (foo) 
{
}
```

It is like, I used `-bl -bli0` whatever I put after `-bli`, I get the same result.

In other words assuming that the content of `test.c` is:

```
while (foo) {
}
```

If I launch `indent test.c -st -bl -bli2 > test.out`, `test.out` is then on my side:

```
while (foo)
{
}
```

Do I miss something or it is a bug in `GNU indent`?

**Update:**

It appears to be `Mac OS X` related, because it works as expected on `Debian 8` with `GNU indent 2.2.11` and on `Ubuntu 14.04` with `GNU indent` `2.2.11` and `2.2.10-2`.

Comment: On my `Debian 8`, with `GNU indent 2.2.11`, it works as expected. Could you post the command you are using?

Comment: @LPs even with this indent my-file.c -st -bl -bli2 > my-file.out it doesn't work on my side

Comment: Really don't know. Probably a bug or something that belongs to libs compatibility.

Comment: thx anyway for you help, it allows me to know that it is either mac os x related or a bug fixed in 2.2.11

Comment: @LPs I've just tested on Ubuntu 14.04 with GNU indent 2.2.11, I confirm that it works as expected

Comment: it sill work on Ubuntu 14.04 with GNU indent 2.2.10-2, it smells like a MacOS X issue

Comment: Do you have `indent` aliased?  Is there an `.indent.pro` file in your home directory?

Comment: ls -al ~/.indent.pro => .indent.pro: No such file or directory

Comment: env | grep INDENT_PROFILE returns nothing too

Comment: If I add -npro to my command it doesn't work too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally realized that I don't use the `indent` version from brew but from `XCode`, the problem comes from the version of `XCode` that doesn't work like `GNU indent`. If I launch the same command with `gindent` instead of `indent` it works as expected. I mean If I launch `gindent test.c -st -bl -bli2 > test.out`, I get what is expected:

```
while (foo)
  {
  }
```